# Java: How to send a XML request?

Tags: java, xml, request

i need to send a xml request in java and catch the response.
How can i do this ?

I search in the google but nothing solid until now.

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: What kind of request is this? Are you trying to do a http post ?

Comment: XMLRPC? Here's a library: http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking to do an HTTP POST, then you could use the [java.net.*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) APIs in Java SE:

```
    try { 
        URL url = new URL(URI);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        // Write your XML to the OutputStream (JAXB is used in this example)
        jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(customer, os);
        os.flush();
        connection.getResponseCode();
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

XML is a data format. If you talk about requests/responses, you need to know the protocol.

My guess is that the protocol you are using is HTTP(S) and you have to do a POST with your XML request, but this is just an educated(?) guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use playframework. It is the easiest web framework I have ever used in Java. It is resembles to rails but in java. Give it a try.

http://www.playframework.org/

It has a nice and easy to use template engine based on groovy. You can set a request format as described here.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/routes

Go for documentation for details. You will implement your first website that can send and get requests in just hours.