# Send an xml file to an url and get it response

Tags: java, xml, request

I am trying to send a xml file to an URL, and it should respond me with an other xml file. I am trying to do this with the code below :

```
        URL url = new URL("url.example.com");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("path\\test.xml");
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(fileReader);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        os.flush();

        connection.getResponseCode();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        try {
            Document docxml = db.parse(connection.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Input Stream : " + docxml.toString());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Input Stream : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        connection.disconnect();
```

When i run the code i'm getting this error :

```
Input Stream : Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL
```

I am sure the url and the file are good, is there any error in my code and the way i send my http request? Or does the error comes from the server or anything?
If you have any idea or suggestion about my code or about what i could do to debug and know where the problem come from, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953631/java-how-to-send-a-xml-request

Comment: Im not sure that this post also mention to get the XML in response

Comment: What about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735839/posting-xml-request-in-java ?